# Modifying what vertices a bone affects

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, vertices

I hope this hasn't been answered somewhere else. I remember having found it a long time ago but I've been looking for the answer for a week with no success. I know there is a way in which you can select manually which vertices a bone moves when animating (something like assigning or removing the influence a bone has on a vertix) , but I can't find the way to do it and I was hoping someone would?

Ps. This isn't the weight painting method

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: if you select a vertex, in the N panel you can see what bones influence it, and how much

Comment: hey thanks! I did find that as an answer somewhere but it's not really what I'm trying to do. There is a way in which you can select a bone, and the vertices that it is affecting light up, you can then remove or assign vertices to that bone

Comment: Do you mean the vertex groups?

Comment: @Leander Hey, i'm not sure if it's the vertex groups tbh- basically what I had done before was manually deselect some vertices which were being left behind when I animated in a previous project because they were being affected by the wrong bone. I somehow managed to do it again in another one, but I can't for the sake of me figure out how I'd done it ( I know better now to save all answers to problems I find but I didn't then! :s)

Comment: Yes, you can do that with vertex groups. These are the groups, that affect the bones and can be manually selected in the 3D Viewport.

Comment: @Leander Ah! okay! Do I have to be in edit mode to be able to do it? I'm going to try now

Comment: Yes, the vertex groups have buttons to select/deselect/add/remove vertices in edit mode. There should be a corresponding vertex group for each bone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116240/discussion-between-cam-and-leander).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @leander for this: The way to do this is to first select the object whose bone influences you are looking to modify. You can then go into edit mode and into the object data properties.

From there you can see a list of the bones affecting the object and by clicking on each one you get to see what vertices it has an influence on (the vertex groups of the bone). You can then remove any unwanted influence or assign an influence it doesn't currently have.